# GUI with RGtk2: clear frame

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk2

I am new to RGtk2 and GUI programming, so I hope my question is not trivial.

I am trying to make a GUI in which I would like to import some kind of .RData and work with them and finally return some plots. Since the dataset I would like to import could change from time to time, I decided to add a function LOAD in the *menubar* and in the *toolbar* that reproduces the command "load" of R.
After having loaded the workspace, I add some *check buttons* in order to decide which sets of data to work with and a *remove-function* which is able to remove the objects that were inherited from the file .RData previously loaded.

Here is the code for the two *callbacks*:

```
# Number of companies & maximum number of companies
numb_comp <- 0
max_length <- 30

# Table Check for Companies
list_check <- vector('list', length=max_length)



### Implementing the callbacks

open_cb <- function(widget, window){
    dialog <- gtkFileChooserDialog("Load a WorkSpace", window, "open",
        "gtk-cancel", GtkResponseType["cancel"], "gtk-open",
        GtkResponseType["accept"])
    want_to_load <- FALSE
    if (dialog$run() == GtkResponseType["accept"])want_to_load <- TRUE
    if (!want_to_load) dialog$destroy()
    else {
        load(dialog$getFilename(),.GlobalEnv)
        eval.parent(substitute(numb_comp <- length(names)))

        table_col <- 6
        table_row <- ceiling(numb_comp/table_col)
        table_check <- gtkTable(rows=table_row,columns=table_col,homogeneous=TRUE)
        l_check <- vector('list',length=numb_comp)

        for (i in 1:length(names)){
            button <- gtkCheckButton(names[i])
            table_check$attach(button, (i-1)%% table_col, ((i-1)%% table_col) + 1,
                    floor((i-1)/table_col), floor((i-1)/table_col)+1)
            l_check[[i]] <- button
            rm(button)
            }
        frame_check$add(table_check)
        eval.parent(substitute(list_check <- l_check))
        statusbar$push(info, paste(" WorkSpace", basename(dialog$getFilename()), 
        "loaded!",sep=" "))
        }
    dialog$destroy()
    }



remove_cb <- function(widget, window){
    dialog <- gtkMessageDialog(main_win,"destroy-with-parent", "question", "yes-no",
        "Do you really want to remove the WorkSpace?")
    want_to_remove <- FALSE
    if (dialog$run() == GtkResponseType["yes"])want_to_remove <- TRUE
    if (!want_to_remove) dialog$destroy()
    else {
            eval.parent(substitute(numb_comp <- 0))
        frame_check$remove(table_check)
        table_col <- 6
        table_row <- ceiling(numb_comp/table_col)
        table_check <- gtkTable(rows=table_row,columns=table_col,homogeneous=TRUE)
        for (i in 1:length(names)){
            rien <- gtkLabel("a")
            table_check$attach(rien, (i-1)%% table_col, ((i-1)%% table_col) + 1,
                    floor((i-1)/table_col), floor((i-1)/table_col)+1)
            }
        frame_check$add(table_check)
        rm(list=c("files","ICDatasetRel","names","shortnames"),inherits=TRUE)
        eval.parent(substitute(list_check <- vector('list',length=0)))
        statusbar$push(info, " Workshop removed.")
        }

    dialog$destroy()
    }
```

This is what I tried to remove the table I had created when using the function *open_cp*. But I saw that it does not work.

Thus, I have two questions:

1. Since the *check buttons* are created in a function, I decided to use a kind of "call by reference" (see *eval.parent(substitute(list_check<-l_check))*) to have control on them when the routine *open_cb* dies. Is it a good idea? Or are there better solutions? I will need to know which buttons are activated to decide which dataset should be taken into account.
2. Using the function I called *remove_cb*, I will destroy all the objects brought by the LOAD operation, but I would like to change also the "physical aspect" of the GUI. In other words, I would like to clear the actual frame or to substitute it with an overlaying frame (with no buttons). Is it possible? If yes, how?

Any help is really highly appreciated.

Comment: Please, if something is not clear I can try to clarify it. Nevertheless, I hope it is quite understandable.